# Groupby-shift, save column

Tags: python, pandas

I try to save column on which I `groupby` when shifting

```
pd.DataFrame({'column1':['Alex', 'Bob', 'Bob'], 'column2':[3, 4, 5]}).groupby('column1').shift(1)
```

I want the final dataframe to have 'Alex', 'Bob' and 'Bob' in the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the shifted values to your existing dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['Alex', 'Bob', 'Bob'], 'column2':[3, 4, 5]})
df['shift']  = df.groupby(['column1']).shift(1)
df = df.set_index('column1')
```